# mathjs integral, not able to install the math-simple-integral

Tags: javascript, math, npm, project, integral

I have been working on a calculator for class that just calculates the integral of an equation like 2x + 5 or (3x^2)/5x. I was thinking that math.js would be the best library to use in regards to finding integrals easily but I am having trouble to install the correct math-simple-integral within math.js, I have in the past just used the script src

```
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/5.1.0/math.min.js"></script>
```

for math.js and all the functions they give works but when I try to install math-simple-integral with the instructions given from https://www.npmjs.com/package/mathjs-simple-integral I can't seem to make the math.integral('x^2 + 2' , 'x') work, even after I input

```
   math.import(require('mathjs-simple-integral'));
```

into my javascript page (which I assume thats where it is to be stated).
I need to know how to install the npm link preferably through a script source.

this is how my my scripts look like the first script src is the original math.js updated to the 5.1 
and the second script is the javascript page in which I code in and do all the functions and console.logs in.

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/5.1.0/math.min.js"></script>

     <script src="../JS/calc/c1-2.js"></script>
```

thank you

Comment: This works for me: `<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.0/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML'></script>
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  displayAlign: "left",
});
</script>`

Comment: Hello it doesnt seem to work with the math.integral function, I was wondering if you knew how to add the math.integral function ?

Comment: @SLaks can you look at the question I edited it for you